# how can i hide that? user used /slash command in discord (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

can i hide that -user used /slash_command - in the embed message create feature?

```
@bot.hybrid_command()
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = SERVID))
async def criar_embed(ctx, titulo: str, descricao: str, cor: discord.Color, footer_text: str = None, field_name: str = None, field_value: str = None, timestamp: bool = False):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=titulo,
        description=descricao,
        color=cor
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41YSLRQ0QYL.jpg')
    
    if footer_text:
        embed.set_footer(text=footer_text)
    
    if field_name and field_value:
        embed.add_field(name=field_name, value=field_value)
    
    if timestamp:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        formatted_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")  # Formato da data e hora
        embed.timestamp = now
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{formatted_time}")
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

the purple lines in the image = censorship

[image of the thing that i'm saying here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiXJD.png)

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Bots will always reply to the user that ran a slash command however it should be possible to make the interaction reply hidden to everyone but the one who used it and then send the embed to the channel by using something like this:

```py
if timestamp:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")  # Formato da data e hora
    embed.timestamp = now
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{formatted_time}")

await ctx.send('Done', hidden=True)
await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```